# Android clean up after dirty Shutdown

Tags: android

I am writing a program which creates various files during operation, and on closing the Activity will remove curtain files and register others in the database.

is there a way to detect when next running the program if the application is was not closed properly (ie if the battery was removed) in order to run a clean-up and fix the database.

I would run it every time however I think it could get quite time consuming.
When necessary the clean-up should be run before staring the main activity (not the one that normally does the clean-up) as it affects the output.

I have code for this clean-up, and am using API 10.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a SharedPreferences boolean variable that you set to true only when you've finished cleaning up. When the app is started, check this value and if it is false, clean up.

See this page for more info on sharedPreferences: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref